# Is it still possible to have transparent background under drawer in nativescript-ui-sidedrawer

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

After updating nativescript-ui-sidedrawer from version 3~ to the newest (6.0.0) I no longer know how to make background of a drawer transparent.
I've read there have been some breaking changes in v4.0.0, and before that it was enough to do:

```
<RadSideDrawer [drawerTransition]="sideDrawerTransition">
    <GridLayout tkDrawerContent rows="auto, *" backgroundColor="transparent">
        ...
    </GridLayout>
    <StackLayout tkMainContent>
        ...
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

Now it seems like there is a view with black background that cant be changed.

Is it still possible to make sidedrawers background transparent?

Note: I'm using angular and only tried it on iOS